# How to get this triangle in matrix?

Tags: c++

[image]

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int n = 5;
void fill_matrix(int (*matrix)[n])
{
    for (int row = 0; row < n; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < n; col++)
            matrix[row][col] = rand() % 201 - 100;
    }

}

void print_matrix(int (*matrix)[n])
{
    for (int row = 0; row < n; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < n; col++)
            cout << setw(4) << matrix[row][col];
        cout << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int matrix[n][n];
    int sum = 0;
    fill_matrix(matrix);
    print_matrix(matrix);

    for (int row = 0; row < n; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < n; col++)
        {
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I can't realize how I can loop over this part of the matrix. The matrix can be a different size. So I can't imagine an algorithm to get the right triangle of the matrix

Comment: What is the problem? Is it a question on how to perform the actual loop? and what do you want to achieve using this loop? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

It is important to realise, that the widest point of the triangle is at its tip.

Let `i = 1`
So going from the top row to the bottom, do:

Start:

- set the last i fields in this row to 1.
- if `i` is smaller than the height of the matrix, increase `i` by one
- else if it is greater than the height, decrease it by one

Go back to start

Answer (score 0):

Consider the generic nested loops used in the posted code to traverse the "matrix", just written in a slightly different way.

```
for (int row = 0; row < n; row++)
{
    int const first_col = 0;
    int const last_col = n;
    for (int col = first_col; col < last_col; col++)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

At the right side of the greyed area in OP's posted image, every row terminates at the boundary of the matrix (so that we don't really need a `last_col` variable, the original condition is fine).

Note, though, that all the matrix elements inside this area are at the *right* (or on) of *both* the leading diagonal and the antidiagonal.

Now, what would be the mathematical equation of the leading diagonal, given the row?

> column = f(row) = row

What about the antidiagonal? Look at its definition (from [Wolfram](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/Antidiagonal)):

> An antidiagonal is defined as a list of elements for which the sum of the indices are equal, where the first element is in the top-right of a matrix

So, given a matrix of size n x n and remembering that in C++ array indices are 0-based, we can say:

> column = g(row) = n - 1 - row

As already noted, the value we need to initialize `first_col` in the outer loop  is the *max* of these two values.